# Checksum mismatch for MD5 and SHA256 but not SHA1

Tags: apt, updates

Received the following from APT indicating that the SHA1 matches but not SHA256 or MD5 of the docker file.  Should I be concerned?

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/docker.io/docker.io_19.03.6-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:a2eab8d37000b633e63fd70fcba4361f6b390d7feb27f986a60b10fe116a20ea
    - SHA1:02065b2bcc95e5de8c6844ae7648324af43ab07d [weak]
    - MD5Sum:fb7a09790f35bccf7cd9b9e4449c7f56 [weak]
    - Filesize:39944200 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:761ddb0db2926f96c1644538b1680aa43b30d30fb46ad0b6d1b65010174dadb4
    - SHA1:02065b2bcc95e5de8c6844ae7648324af43ab07d [weak]
    - MD5Sum:f45f68d2e593568c6c98b261d62f1d91 [weak]
    - Filesize:39944200 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Fri, 28 Feb 2020 23:53:20 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Your file is corrupt. Download it again.